# Build Assimp with mingw32

Tags: c++, mingw32, building, assimp

Hello i tried to compile Assimp with mingw32.

But during compilation multiple errors appeard.

The first was:

```
C:\Users\MY_NAME\Downloads\assimp-5.0.1\assimp-5.0.1\code\SMD\SMDLoader.cpp:579:12: error: 'strtok_s' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'strtok_r'?
```

I found a solution for the this problem,i changed the source code and it worked but i don't found a solution for the second problem.
The second error was:

```
c:\users\MY_NAME\downloads\assimp-5.0.1\assimp-5.0.1\contrib\zip\src\zip.h:30:15: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef long int ssize_t' 
30 | typedef long  ssize_t;  /* byte count or error */
```

here is line 30 from zip.h :

```
typedef long  ssize_t;  /* byte count or error */
```

To make it more clear,i decided to show you  a block of code.
here is a block of code from  line 27 to 31 in zip.h

```
#ifdef _WIN64
typedef long long  ssize_t;  /* byte count or error */
#else
typedef long  ssize_t;  /* byte count or error *
#endif
```

I'm using mingw32 with gcc (9.2.0)

Can someone explain why the build fail?

Comment: What MinGW distribution do you use, and how exactly do you build assimp? If I were you, I'd install [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org), from which you can install prebuilt assimp (and as a bonus, the latest GCC). And in general, I find it to be better at building libraries than most other MinGW distributions.

Comment: I use Mingw32 with gcc(9.2.0) (MinGW.org GCC Build-2)
first i configured the Assimp with cmake:
->  cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" CMakelists.txt -DASSIMP_BUILD_ASSIMP_TOOLS=OFF -S ./  -B ./BUILD_ASSIMP 
after configuring i changed to BUILD_ASSIMP and use mingw32-make to build Assimp.

Comment: I suggest switching to MSYS2. The version of MinGW from mingw.org is inferior in some ways (e.g. no multithreading support in the standard library, last time I checked), and also outdated (9.2 compared to 10.2 in MSYS2). MSYS2 will let you download prebuilt Assimp. Even if you prefer to build it manually, MSYS2 might be better at it than your version of MinGW.

Comment: i get my distribution from  www.mingw.org

Comment: Yup, noticed your edit to the comment.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this issue is already closed in our current master. Could you please try the latest from [Asset-Importer-Lib@github](https://github.com/assimp/assimp)?

Comment: I can confirm. I was able to build on current `master` using current MinGW and CMake versions.